# Merge seperate rows based on unique identifier column

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, one with person data, and another with a volunteer look up code:

```
Person Table
| ID |  UID  | First | Last | VolCode | VolYear
| 00 | 09123 | John  | Doe  | A01     | 2016
| 01 | 09123 | John | Doe   | A02     | 2016
| 02 | 09123 | John | Doe   | A03     | 2016
```

-

```
Vol Table
| ID | VolCode | Name      |
| 00 | A01     | Something |
| 01 | A02     | Something |
| 02 | A03     | Something |
```

Desired result:

```
Results
| p.UID | p.First | p.Last | v.VolCodes  | v.volYear   |
| 09123 | John    | Does   | A01,A02,A03 | 2016        |
```

Is there a way in SQL to create a column with a concatenated list of VolCodes such as in the desired result?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Most SQL systems do not easily support string aggregation.  If possible, I would strongly consider doing that logic in the display layer (report, form, web page, etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your DBMS.

**PostgreSQL** The aggregate function is called [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
SELECT a, array_agg(b) 
FROM (VALUES (1, 'abc'), (1, 'def'), (1, 'xyz')) t ( a, b ) 
GROUP BY a;
```

which gives

```
 a |   array_agg   
---+---------------
 1 | {abc,def,xyz}
```

**MySQL / MariaDB**
The aggregate function is called [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030090/mysql-array-aggregate-function-like-postgresql-array-agg).
Probably like this:

```
SELECT a, group_concat(b) 
FROM (VALUES (1, 'abc'), (1, 'def'), (1, 'xyz')) t ( a, b ) 
GROUP BY a;
```

Your expected result only seems to be using the first of the tables. Are you sure that you don't have a Foreign Key reference from `person.volCode` referencing to `vol.id`? The question is how you aggregate your rows together - do you `GROUP BY person.uid`? By `person.year`?
The query for your example could be (using only the `person` table):

```
SELECT uid, first, last, array_agg(volCode) AS "volCodes", volYear 
FROM person  
GROUP BY uid, first, last, volYear;
```

You should be aware that this does not have atomic values in the `volCodes` column (not first normal form) and you cannot easily continue processing this column. Before aggregation, you had 3 rows, which you could have filtered easily using a `WHERE` clause. After aggregation, it's much more difficult to filter on parts of the aggregated values `volCodes`. Also, an index on the `GROUP BY` fields may speed up the grouping. We still don't know which values should be aggregated on. I'm just assuming all 4 columns (`uid, first, last, volYear`) here - it could be different though - it depends on you.

If you want to `GROUP BY uid` only, then the columns `first, last, volYear` are multi-value. You can either also `array_agg` them like this

```
SELECT uid, 
       array_agg(first), 
       array_agg(last), 
       array_agg(volCode) AS "volCodes", 
       array_agg(volYear) 
FROM person  
GROUP BY uid;
```

which will carry the same `firstname` three times (because of your example table data).

Or you can choose the minimum value or something with

```
SELECT uid, 
       MIN(first), -- chooses the alphabetically ordered firstname
       MIN(last), 
       array_agg(volCode) AS "volCodes", 
       MIN(volYear) 
FROM person  
GROUP BY uid;
```

which is probably not really what you want though.