# Join 2 tables via UNION group by a given field and get only the latest of the group

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building an email inbox within a little dashboard. Is a custom email client using other APIs. The way I prepared the DB structure is as follows:

**The `incoming` table**

```
╔════╦════════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ id ║     email_from     ║     email_to      ║               email_body                ║         date         ║
╠════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ stack@overflow.com ║ mitch@example.com ║ Your question has a downvote for newbie ║ 2017-12-28T00:00:00Z ║
║  2 ║ stack@exchange.com ║ mitch@example.com ║ You gotta learn SQL, buddy :/           ║ 2017-12-28T00:01:43Z ║
║  3 ║ stack@overflow.com ║ mitch@example.com ║ Guess what? 42                          ║ 2017-12-28T00:05:00Z ║
║  3 ║ stack@overflow.com ║ mitch@example.com ║ This is a bot, stop responding          ║ 2017-12-28T00:10:00Z ║
╚════╩════════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

**The `outgoing` table**

```
╔════╦═══════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ id ║    email_from     ║      email_to      ║             email_body             ║         date         ║
╠════╬═══════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ mitch@example.com ║ stack@overflow.com ║ That is bad news                   ║ 2017-12-28T00:00:50Z ║
║  2 ║ mitch@example.com ║ stack@exchange.com ║ I know :(                          ║ 2017-12-28T00:01:45Z ║
║  3 ║ mitch@example.com ║ stack@overflow.com ║ Answer to the Ultimate Question... ║ 2017-12-28T00:07:42Z ║
╚════╩═══════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

So, I want to do a little inbox like Gmail, where you see the list of all the emails, grouped by email address (or conversations) and ordered by date showing the latest at the top, and within each conversation, showing only the last message of that conversation.

---

**My query attempt**

```
SELECT `email_from` as `thread_email`, `email_body`, `date`
FROM (
SELECT `email_from`, `email_body`, `date` FROM `incoming`
UNION
SELECT `email_to` as `email_from`, `email_body`, `date` FROM `outgoing`
) AS t_union

GROUP BY `email_from`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Results in:

```
╔════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║    thread_email    ║               email_body                ║         date         ║
╠════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ stack@exchange.com ║ You gotta learn SQL, buddy :/           ║ 2017-12-28T00:01:43Z ║
║ stack@overflow.com ║ Your question has a downvote for newbie ║ 2017-12-28T00:00:00Z ║
╚════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

It shows the results from the `incoming` table only.

---

**My expected result**

- Grouped by email address, this represents a conversation (known as `thread_email`, basically one row per `thread_email`)
- Each row (or conversation, or `thread_email`) shows just the latest message of that `thread_email` (the last message could be incoming or outgoing)
- Ordered by date (most recent first)

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║    thread_email    ║           email_body           ║         date         ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ stack@overflow.com ║ This is a bot, stop responding ║ 2017-12-28T00:10:00Z ║
║ stack@exchange.com ║ I know :(                      ║ 2017-12-28T00:01:45Z ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

**SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed9642/4**

Is this the newbie way of achieving this? Any suggestions for another database structure that this easier but also cleaner and ordered?

Comment: Any reason why you use two tables instead of one?

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to build this web application as organized as I can. Also, I found this 2-table based structure simpler to build the specific conversation pages (my question is to build the main index of conversations). Do you have any suggestions to improve my current structure? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon said, if `group by` your data, that reduce the data to one row, but if you only use `order by` clause, you will still get duplicated data, it will bring all the data from union table.

The `group by` clause has a `having` clause too but it seems to only work with numbers, like `count(*) > 2` and other stuff.

In [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) we have something called `array_agg`, that transform some data into array and then we can access it as a array.

In MySQL, the only thing similar that I found was [group_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030090/mysql-array-aggregate-function-like-postgresql-array-agg) that transform all data with the same grouped by statement in a string joined with ',', so, idk if this solve your problem, but you can try this and treat the result on application side, instead of treat on SQL side.

You can use this like:

```
select email_from, group_concat(email_body), date from (
  select email_from, email_body, date from incoming union all
  select email_to as email_from, email_body, date from outgoing
) as t_union group by email_from order by date desc;
```

OR, in last case, in a non opmized way to do:

```
select email_from, email_body, date from (
  select email_from, email_body, date from incoming union all
  select email_to as email_from, email_body, date from outgoing
) as t_union_1 where date in (
  select max(date) from (
    select email_from, email_body, date from incoming union all
    select email_to as email_from, email_body, date from outgoing
  ) as t_union group by email_from order by date desc
);
```

Comment: The *last case* seems to work as expected. I hope it performs well with 10,000 records. Thank you very much, @Maximillian!