# How to Concat More than one vertical value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to CONCAT **More than one Vertical varchar values** in sql

Table Structure:-

```
    ***Country  State**
        India    Delhi
        India    UP
        India    Bihar*

Output Like this:-

**Country        State**
   India      Delhi, UP, Bihar
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030090/mysql-array-aggregate-function-like-postgresql-array-agg?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
SELECT Country, group_concat(state SEPARATOR ', ') state
FROM taberName
GROUP BY Country
```

**DEMO**

> [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44645f/2)