# Rails processes data from large table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scalability

I have a topic_followers table with schema like this

```
id, user_id, topic_id, creation_date, modified_date
```

I want to generate a hash from this table with user_id as key and an array of topic_ids this user is following as value. Currently, I'm trying to use following code to achieve that:

```
topic_followers = TopicFollower.select("user_id, topic_id")
topic_follower_hash = {}
topic_followers.each do |topic_follower|
  topic_follower_hash[topic_follower.user_id] = topic_follower_hash[topic_follower.user_id] || []
  topic_follower_hash[topic_follower.user_id] << topic_follower.topic_id
end
```

The thing is, this is a large table and I'm afraid it'll blow out my memory. I googled around a bit and some articles suggested using find_in_batches. I don't think it fits my need though, since some topics a user is following may not be in the current batch. Wondering what's the recommended practice here to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: are you using SQL or NoSQL?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is actually aggregation.

```
group_by user_id
inset all topic_id inside an array
```

Your final response would look something like this:

```
[{"id": "user_id", "topic_ids": ["topic_id1", ...]}...]
```

Then use a single loop to convert this array of hash to a single hash.

For reference to aggregation in Postgre use this:
[Aggregation in Postgre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030090/mysql-array-aggregate-function-like-postgresql-array-agg)